# Links broken on HTML file on thumbdrive

Tags: html, hyperlink, filesystems

I am currently programming an HTML file on a thumb drive. I have included links in the code. Because it is on a USB, whenever I move it to a different computer the letter assigned to the USB changes, so the links are broken. On my laptop, it is labeled as drive F, so the links are addressed to F:\Filename. But on my desktop, it is drive J, so the links are addressed to a non existing directory.

I have tried doing the name of the USB instead of just the letter and that doesn't work.

On my laptop, the links are coded as Link. On the desktop, it is assigned a different letter so the links are broken. I can change the link to Link but whenever I switch between the two computers the links must change, and it is very tedious to go through all couple hundred lines of code and change all of the links, even using ctrl+f.

I expect the links to show the image or open the other HTML file on my thumb drive, but it either shows the Alt text or shows the error message saying, "Your file was not found It may have been moved or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND". I am working on a Windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this.

1) You can change the path to relative path by using '../path' to back up from one folder or '/path' to target a specific folder.

2) You can change the letter of your Thumb Drive. Go to Start, type diskmgmt.msc and press enter.

Right-click on your USB Drive and click 'Change Drive Letter and Paths' then click 'Change'.

You can now assign the following drive letter to F: or others.

Comment: Oh I just got I to work! I looked up what you meant by /path and came across relative and absolute links. So now the code looks like this: <a href="\Filename>Link</a> Now it is a relative link. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I was trying to use absolute links, which means that the link path cannot change. I want it to be able to change. I came across relative links, which means that the path can change. So instead of the code looking like this: Link It looks like this: Link